# Search and replace in all files for context action in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

After upgrading a project to PHP8, I'd like to refactor my code to use the new features, eg. replacing

```php
if (strpos($link, 'somestring') === false) {
```

with

```php
if (!str_contains($link, 'somestring')) {
```

PhpStorm offers a context menu for this action which is great. It also means that PhpStorm can detect these constructs.

But: Is there a possibility to replace all occurrences automatically, maybe in combination with the "Replace in files" menu? Of course a regex would also do the job, but a full automatic process would be more comfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Find which inspection is this.** For this:

   - Place caret on the highlighted part (on `strpos` in this case)
   - Invoke Intentions/Quick Fix menu (<kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> on most keymaps or via light bulb icon using a mouse)
   - Expand the most appropriate option (<kbd>Arrow Right</kbd>)
     [image]
   - Select "Edit inspection profile settings" -- it will take you to that inspection so you can **clearly see its name** and check what is does (*although in this particular case it is not really necessary as the name is already shown on the first screenshot; but in other cases it can have different text there*).
     [image]
2. **Run that particular inspection.**

   - Use  `Code | Analyze Code | Run Inspection by Name...` (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Shift + I</kbd> here on Windows keymap).
   - Locate that inspection there
   - Run it on a desired scope (e.g. a folder/custom scope/whole project etc)
     [image]
3. The "Problems" toolwindow will be activated and will list all places where this inspection is triggered. You can do the batch fix here (on a file scope, not all occurrences at once though -- not all quick fixes have "fix all found occurrences at once" option).

   [image]

**P.S.** You can skip some steps (1.4, 2.1 & 2.2) by simply selecting `Run inspection on...` on the first screenshot *if you know for sure* that it is the right inspection.

---

Another approach / option -- use **Rector** that can do quite a few of such upgrades in automated way. It can be integrated with PhpStorm as of 2022.2 version (and you can always run it from a command line).

- https://getrector.org/
- https://github.com/rectorphp/rector
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2022/08/phpstorm-2022-2-is-now-available/#Rector_support